# Ways to autorun my C# app during startup in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, registry, autorun

I currently have problem in making my app autorun during startup in windows 8. I have tried to put the app in the registry. In fact I have tried both Local Machine and Current User approach:

```
RegistryKey rkHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey rkRun;
RegistryKey rkHKCU = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey rkRun1;

rkRun = rkHKLM.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rkRun1 = rkHKCU.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    rkRun.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath);
    rkRun1.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath);
}
else
{
    rkRun.DeleteValue("MyApp");
    rkRun1.DeleteValue("MyApp");
}
```

This method does not work in Windows 8. But I don't have this problem in windows 7 or XP.
Anything different for Windows 8? Is it there is any new approach?

- For your info, I have set the app to run as admin but still doesn't autorun on startup.

Comment: Work out the reg key manually with regedit, then start coding

Comment: How do you know that your program did not run? Perhaps it runs and crashes immediately, perhaps because you're attempting to run it under an account that has insufficient rights for the actions it's trying to perform. What does your program actually do? Does the event log give any indication of failure?

Answer (score 0):

Add a link or batch file file to:

c:\Users\ (username) \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

you could probably replace `c:\Users\ (username) \AppData\Roaming` with `"%AppData%"` in your code by

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData");
```

Comment: I have tried manually putting my app's shortcut into the startup folder.. but it still cannot autorun during startup..

Comment: Hmmm. Very strange. It works perfectly for me. I know this may sound silly, but at the DOS prompt if you type echo %UserName%, does the user name match the c:\User\<UserName> you are using?

Comment: Another thing to look at go to Task Manager (<ctrl><alt><del> then select task manager) or run taskmgr.exe, and then click on the Startup tab and see if it appears there.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a shortcut in:
*c:\Users\{login name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup* should run the application when you log in.

Optionally, you could create **task**. You can in the trigger choose whether it should run on log-in or when the computer starts.

The "[Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)" is a helpful library for creating tasks programmatically.