# Only can auto startup my application using the built-in adminstrator account in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8, administrator

Referring to my previous post:
[Ways to autorun my C# app during startup in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993762/ways-to-autorun-my-c-sharp-app-during-startup-in-windows-8)

I have performed the suggested ways but still cannot auto start my app everytime my windows 8 restart.

Recently I have found out a way but I don't understand why must I do it this way.
I enabled the built-in administrator account in Windows8 (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html). I sign in using this account and my app can auto start.

Do you know why? Is there a way not using this way by changing anything in the source code? I prefer to use the user Account.

Comment: Without the previous question, this question becomes meaningless. You're just asking the same question again.

Comment: I'm just wondering why is it using the built-in Admin account can work but other Admin user cannot work.

Comment: Most likely UAC.  Does your program request administrator privilege?  Such programs are usually prohibited from running automatically.

Comment: Yes. I need to run admin administrator..